# React function component seems to be one state behind current state (useState/useEffect hook)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I'm building a react-app that rolls a dice in a certain interval, shows all the latest
rolls and lets the user try to guess the next throw (just to give a simple idea).

I'll try to give you an overview of the important parts of my code. First the main view:
(and here is a working example https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-sound-ydcevo?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import DiceComponent from "./dice-component";

function View() {
  const [dice, setDice] = useState(0);
  const diceRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <DiceComponent setDice={setDice} diceRef={diceRef} dice={dice} />
      current throw: {dice}
    </div>
  );
}
export default View;
```

and the dice component:

```
import Dice from "react-dice-roll";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

function DiceComponent({ diceRef, setDice, dice }) {
  const roll = () => {
    getRoll();
    rollDice();
  };

  const getRoll = () => {
    let diceRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
    setDice(diceRoll);
  };

  const rollDice = () => {
    if (diceRef && diceRef.current) {
      diceRef.current.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
      diceRef.current.children[0].click();
      diceRef.current.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      roll();
    }, 3500);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [dice, diceRef]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={diceRef} style={{ pointerEvents: "none" }}>
        <Dice size={100} cheatValue={dice} key={"dice"} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default DiceComponent;
```

And to give a quick explanation about the dice. I fetch a roll number from my BE with the fetch as you can see. The dice is supposed to show this fetched number (the dice var) after I roll it. This is possible with the `cheatValue={dice}`, which lets the dice always roll to the given number of `cheatValue`. After I fetch and set my variables, I want to roll the dice. I achieve this with `useRef` and calling a click with it.
Normally the dice would only roll if it gets clicked. But because the dice is not supposed to be clicked, but rather just spin on its own, I create a custom click event to trigger the roll.

Everything works fine so far, but I have one problem, that i can't seem to fix. In the main view I display the current dice for testing and it shows that my dice component always rolls the last dice number and not the current one. So it's always one behind, but I want it to always throw the actual current dice number that was fetched.

I tried to put the `useEffect` and all the fetch and roll method into my main view, but that didn't change anything.
I use `useEffect` because I had the problem, that my fetch call was always called multiple times, which messed up my project. Thats why I need `useEffect`.

Any questions, or ideas on how I can achieve this? My project is a lot bigger than this part that I'm showing, so I hope I got the problem out. If something is not clear please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because when `rollDice()` is called, it fires the click event on the `Dice` component with the current value of `dice`, not the one that you just calculated and passed to `setDice()`.

You can treat firing the `click` event as a side-effect by wrapping it in a `useEffect()`, which will run after the compoenent gets rendered with the new value of `dice`.

```js
import Dice from "react-dice-roll";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

function DiceComponent({ diceRef, setDice, dice }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (diceRef && diceRef.current) {
      diceRef.current.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
      diceRef.current.children[0].click();
      diceRef.current.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    }
  }, [dice, diceRef]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      let diceRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
      setDice(diceRoll);
    }, 3500);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [setDice]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={diceRef} style={{ pointerEvents: "none" }}>
        <Dice size={100} cheatValue={dice} key={"dice"} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default DiceComponent;
```

You'll notice that I moved some things around. For example, having the `useEffect` of the interval depend only on `setDice` means that you'll have the same instance of the interval for the life of the component.

Also, it's worth keeping an eye out for the hooks lint rules, they are generally quite useful.